# Return highest value php

Tags: php

How to find max value ,return the only one number with the highest value

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
foreach($graphData as $gt) {
    echo $gt['pView'].',';
}
?>
```

Result:

```
0,0,0,18,61,106,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

im try something like this

```
<?php
    $str = '';
        foreach ($graphData as $gt){
            $str = array($gt['pView'],);}
            $max =max($str);
            if($max == 0){echo '20';}
                else
            {echo $max +20;}
?>
```

and result is always **20**, but shold be 106 + 20

Whats wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($graphData as $gt) {
    array_push($arr, $gt['pView']);
}
$max = max($arr);
if ($max === 0) {
    $max = 20;
}
else {
    $max += 20;
}
echo $max;
```

As seen in the [PHP documentation for `max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php), the function `max` can accept a single array of values as an argument. If that's the case, it returns the largest in the array.

Comment: its back `20202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020`
and alo there is error PHP Warning:  max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your formatting. I edited my answer, see if it works now.

Answer (score 3):

The example code has serious issues. The first is indenting, after fixing which we have

```
foreach ($graphData as $gt){
    $str = array($gt['pView'],);
}
```

It should be obvious that this won't really do anything, as it keeps resetting `$str` to one value in the array after another without doing anything else in the meantime (also, why are you assigning an array to a variable named `$str`?).

The solution is a straightforward case of iteration:

```
$max = reset($gt);
foreach ($gt as $item) {
    $max = max($item['pView'], $max);
}

echo "Final result = ".($max + 20);
```

There are also cuter ways to write this, for example

```
$max = max(array_map(function($item) { return $item['pView']; }, $gt));
```

or if you are using PHP 5.5

```
$max = max(array_column($gt, 'pView'));
```

Comment: In retrospect, this is actually the best answer. I appreciate the use of `array_map` and `array_column`. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```php
sort($grafdata);
if($grafdata == 0) {
    echo '20';
} else {
    echo $grafdata + 20;
}
```